# Navigation Controller from a View Controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I'm using .xib files in an app. And I want to have two view controllers normal way and from the third view controller, embed it in a navigation view controller. Here's an illustration of how I want it.

[image]

I know I can embed a navigation controller in a modally presented view controller like this.

```
let firstVC = FirstViewController(nibName: firstViewController, bundle: nil)
let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: firstVC)
presentViewController(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

But if I embed it in a navigation controller and push it, the app crashes with the error **Pushing the same view controller instance more than once is not supported**.

```
let firstVC = FirstViewController(nibName: firstViewController, bundle: nil)
let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: firstVC)
navController.pushViewController(firstVC, animated: true)
```

Is it possible to do this at all? If so, can someone please explain how?

Thank you.

**NOTE:** Don't confuse the code snippets with the diagram above. The `firstViewController` in the code is **not** the first view controller in the diagram.

Comment: Are you referring firstViewController as the first image in above diagram? If so how are you navigating through first image to second? Through presenting?

Comment: Oh no no, the code snippet is not related to the diagram above. Sorry I forgot to mention that.

Comment: @Isuru How did you resolved your issue?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that FirstViewcontroller,Secondviewcontroller,Thirdviewcontroller are the three view controllers. then the transition from second to third view controller use the code given below.

```
Secondviewcontroller *second=[[Secondviewcontroller alloc]init];
UINavigationController *nav=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController: second];
[self presentViewController:nav animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Comment: Hi, this is how I already do the modal presentation. What I need is to push the view controller. Not present it modally.

Comment: you mean push to the third viewcontroller?

Comment: Exactly. Push to the third view controller and have it embedded inside a navigation controller.

Comment: If you want to push from second view controller, second view controller should have a navigation controller. unless you can't push from that view controller.

Answer (score 1):

1. use the first view controller as the root view controller of the UINavigationController
2. use the following method to present your next view controller

> [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated: YES];

3. in the viewWillAppear method, if you wanna hide the navigation bar, use

> [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];

If you wanna show the navigation bar, use

> [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];